# Use of Activity methods

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

Can someone neatly explain the use of following Activity methods :

- **onStart**
- **onResume**
- **onPause**
- **onStop**
- **onDestroy**
- **onRestart**

I know these are basic methods one should know while programming in Android. But frankly I have not been able to implement these methods in my applications in a wise way.

Stone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this links

http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/android-activity-lifecycle/

http://www.technicaljar.com/?p=517

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/13/android-activity-life-cycle/

http://www.itgalary.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=680

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting probably the most important, onCreate. Try reading up on this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: onCreate is probably what we use the most :) So I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the official documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html